# Will a MySQL SELECT statement interrupt INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table that keep gaining new records every 5 seconds.

The questions are

1. can I run query on this set of data that may takes more than 5 seconds?
2. if **SELECT** statement takes more than 5s, will it affect the scheduled **INSERT** statement?
3. what happen when **INSERT** statement invoked while **SELECT** is still running, will **SELECT** get the newly inserted records?

Comment: I think you should read about ACID on databases, and also look at the specific storage engine you're using for your tables, among others. As it currently stands, this question is too broad and the context is not entirely clear.

Comment: Thanks @ray. I understand that locking database can prevent messing up the SELECT statement. Now what is the good practice to do when I need the data for calculations while those data will be updated within short period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go over your questions and some of the comments you added later.

> 1. can I run query on this set of data that may takes more than 5 seconds?

*Can* you? Yes. *Should* you? It depends. In a MySQL configuration I set up, any query taking longer than 3 seconds was considered slow and logged accordingly. In addition, you need to keep in mind the *frequency* of the queries you intend to run.

For example, if you try to run a 10 second query every 3 seconds, you can probably see how things won't end well. If you run a 10 second query every few hours or so, then it becomes more tolerable for the system.

That being said, slow queries can often benefit from optimizations, such as not scanning the entire table (i.e. search using primary keys), and using the `explain` keyword to get the database's query planner to tell you how it intends to work on that internally (e.g. is it using PKs, FKs, indices, or is it scanning all table rows?, etc).

> 2. if SELECT statement takes more than 5s, will it affect the scheduled INSERT statement?

"Affect" in what way? If you mean "prevent insert from actually inserting until the select has completed", that depends on the storage engine. For example, MyISAM and InnoDB are different, and that includes locking policies. For example, MyISAM tends to lock entire tables while InnoDB tends to lock specific rows. InnoDB is also ACID-compliant, which means it can provide certain integrity guarantees. You should read the docs on this for more details.

> 3. what happen when INSERT statement invoked while SELECT is still running, will SELECT get the newly inserted records?

Part of "what happens" is determined by how the specific storage engine behaves. Regardless of what happens, the database is designed to answer application queries in a way that's consistent.

As an example, if the `select` statement were to lock an entire table, then the `insert` statement would have to wait until the `select` has completed and the lock has been released, meaning that the app would see the results *prior* to the `insert`'s update.

> I understand that locking database can prevent messing up the SELECT statement.

It can also put a potentially unacceptable performance bottleneck, especially if, as you say, the system is inserting lots of rows every 5 seconds, and depending on the frequency with which you're running your queries, and how efficiently they've been built, etc.

> what is the good practice to do when I need the data for calculations while those data will be updated within short period?

My recommendation is to simply accept the fact that the calculations are based on a snapshot of the data at the specific point in time the calculation was requested and to let the database do its job of ensuring the consistency and integrity of said data. When the app requests data, it should trust that the database has done its best to provide the most up-to-date piece of *consistent* information (i.e. not providing a row where some columns have been updated, but others yet haven't).

With new rows coming in at the frequency you mentioned, *reasonable* users will understand that the results they're seeing are based on data available *at the time of request*.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth response. The reason I'm having this question is that I will be needing these data to run AI learning code which will takes more than minutes while the data is gaining new records at a frequency of seconds. I think I still have to find a way to separate database for AI and database for pure recording purpose. Please let me know if you have any ideas.

Comment: @ClintonLam Is it possible for you to set time boundaries for your queries? For example, you could select all the rows added between 9am - 9:59am, and process them. Then select all the rows added between 10am - 10:59am, and process them, and so on. The time intervals would be up to you to decide, but that's something that sounds reasonable. The question is if it makes sense in your context. My area is not AI, but that particular context is different from the original question.

Comment: Yes, I could select all rows between the said period. I just wonder will simple Select statement cost more than few seconds for 100m+ records.

Comment: @ClintonLam There's only one way to find out how long it'll really take. You should start with small intervals (e.g. 5 minutes worth of rows), or you could instead set a limit on the number of rows, which could be more predictable (e.g. max of 10K rows per select). You also need to consider overall system load, speed, and other factors, as well as network bandwidth if the program sending the queries is in a different system, etc. Things like that would be way too specific for your particular case and I can't do much more without actually being there and working directly on the problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

All of your questions are related to locking of table.
Your all questions depend on the way database is configured.
Read : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-table-locking/

Comment: I think this response should've been a comment, since it does not really answer anything; it simply re-directs the OP to the appropriate subject with a link.

Comment: @DNAj Thanks for the reference. The problem is I need to update/insert into the table within short period. If I lock the table before inserting, I won't have enough time to do the calculations, which if I start the query, I would miss or interrupt the next insert statement. Is there any work around on this matter?

Comment: Locking is definetely not a good solution.The only way is to first understanding how the isolation level work in your database.This is going to define whether you'll get the latest data or not. Secondly try and tune the queries. By doing some runs you should try to get some timings and based on those timing probably you should define your strategy  as may be you want to use little smaller set at one time or may be hold older records in memory kind of thing. This all depends on your requirement and performance of your code.

Answer (score 0):

## Perform Select Statement While insert statement working

If you want to perform a select statement during insert SQL is performing, you should check by open new connection and close connection every time. i.e If I want to insert lots of records, and want to know that last record has inserted by selecting query. I must have to open connection and close connection in for loop or while loop.

```
# send a request to store data
   insert statement working // take a long time

# select statement in while loop.
  while true:
      cnx.open()
      select statement
      cnx.close
      //break while loop if you get the result
```